# iOS CBPeripheral Services not Being Updated

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I am having some trouble with a CBPeripheral that has it's services updated: my physical device has a button that updates the advertising services but my app still reads the old services in the delegate method `didDiscoverServices`.

Although when I discover the peripheral in `didDiscoverPeripheral`, I can see the services are up-to-date there.

If I run the app again, the old services are still there! It seems the only way to get my app to discover the new services is turning the Bluetooth off and on again. Even uninstalling/reinstalling my app is not enough.

Does iOS cache the services forever? Is there a way to reset/erase the cache?